# VB error in scripting, i have thi code running this should output 2 digit suffix but there is one user generates 3 digit suffix

Tags: vb.net

```
While true
   i= i + 1
   Dim centralAccount As String = StringFormat("{0}{1:00}",accountPrefix, i)
```

This should be output: GH20 (I get the G and H from the firstname and lastname of the user)

however there is atleast one user whose been created as GH200. What could be the problem

Comment: 00 doesn't prevent it from showing more than two digits, so if the value of `i` is actually 200, then you'll get GH200.

Comment: What could have been the fix to this problem? to prevent this from happening I am stuck for a solution.

Comment: What do you want to do? Prevent `i` going over two digits? I'm assuming you need the central account to be unique, so how do you want to preserve the uniqueness?

Comment: Ohh that is actually right also, I have a condition that the code will proceed only if the Letter condition is unique. Is it possible to limit it to 2 digit only? Thank you.

Comment: Stop asking us to design your application. Of course it's possible to prevent a number being more than 99 but that's not the point. You need to do the design yourself and then, if you have a problem implementing it, explain what that design is. YOU need to work out what the rules are first. "limit it to 2 digit only" is not a rule. THINK about how you would do this if it were a manual process. THAT is how you do it in code as well. If you don't know how to do it manually then it's too soon to be asking a question here. You need to know what you are doing before you try to do it.

Comment: Okay, I am new in this language so some things does not really make sense to me. Thanks for  commenting BTW. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user enters their first and last name and you want to return a unique account. This account will consist of the user's initials and the numbers 00 to 99.

1. Get the user's intials.
2. Provide the numbers 00 t0 99
3. Check if the account is unique.

Next we have a branch in out task. The code will do 4 or 5

4. If it is unique we're done.
5. If it is not unique try again with a different number.

Step 5 is the reason for the loop. We keep trying with different numbers until we get a unique account or we have tried all the numbers.

We need the counter for the Do loop so we don't have an endless loop when a particular set of initials already has accounts 00 to 99. In that case the loop is exited and and empty string is returned.

```
Private AccountList As New List(Of String)
Dim AcctNum As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Account = GetCentralAccount(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    If Account = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("There are no accounts available with your initials. Try your middle name.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MessageBox.Show($"Your Account is {Account}")
End Sub
Private Function GetCentralAccount(FirstName As String, LastName As String) As String
    'Step 1
    Dim accountPrefix = FirstName.First & LastName.First
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Do Until Counter = 99 'we have tried all the numbers with these initials and they are all taken
        'Create the new account
        Dim centralAccount = $"{accountPrefix}{AcctNum:00}"
        AcctNum += 1
        'Step 2
        'We don't want a number > 99. (two digits)
        If AcctNum > 99 Then
            AcctNum = 0
        End If
        'Step 3 We add each account to a list then we can check for uniqueness
        If Not AccountList.Contains(centralAccount) Then
            'Step 4.
            AccountList.Add(centralAccount)
            Return centralAccount
        End If
        Counter += 1
        'Step 5. We try again with a new account number
    Loop
    Return ""
End Function
```